# How to get the first created folder instead the last?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, directoryinfo

```
var lastWrittenFolder = new DirectoryInfo(textBoxPath.Text).GetDirectories()
                       .OrderByDescending(d => d.LastWriteTimeUtc).First();
```

this is working fine for getting the latest created folder.

but how do i get the first created folder ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the OrderBy function, and the keySelector parameter:

```
var lastWrittenFolder = new DirectoryInfo(textBoxPath.Text).GetDirectories()
                   .OrderBy(d => d.CreationTimeUtc).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

following code will help you.

```
static void Main()
{
    var folderPath = "your-folder-path";

    var directories = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath).GetDirectories();

    foreach (var item in directories.OrderBy(m => m.LastWriteTime))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.LastWriteTime + " " + item.Name);
    }


    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: There was nothing in the question about using the `Console`. It just adds confusion to include unnecessary code.

Comment: Actually, your answer doesn't even address the question. You've posted code similar to the OP's but it doesn't do what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [Min](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min?view=net-7.0), so you need the record which has the minimum creation date.

```
var firstCreatedFolder = new DirectoryInfo(textBoxPath.Text).GetDirectories()
                       .Min(d => d.CreationTimeUtc);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already there. Just instead of sorting the folder in reverse order ( bottom to top) just sort them from top to bottom and then select the first one like you did.

Here is correct code :

```
var lastWrittenFolder = new DirectoryInfo(path).GetDirectories().OrderBy(d => d.LastWriteTimeUtc).First();
```